# Rasterizing in R does not seem to handle 'islands' well

Tags: r, rasterize

I'm trying to rasterize shape files and I notice a very annoying artifact. If the shapfile contains a shape of a road that fully encloses a region than that whole region is identified with the class road in the raster.

In the images below there is an example. The white ares should be roads, but instead of just the road the entire region enclosed by the road is white.

[image]
[image]

How can I counter this?

The line of code I use is
     raster::rasterize( shape , r, field =   as.numeric( shape$number))
With shape the shape, r the a raster object with the required extent.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data (a clip of the shp)? And maybe a plot of the expected output (shapefile VS raster). It's not clear where is the issue on your images.

Comment: I will try. The isue in the image is the large white area. White should be road. This is a thin shape that surrounds a residential area, but for some reason the area that the polygon surounds is given the colour white as well.